# How to generate an array like this from the url query params

Tags: javascript, arrays, url, query-string

From this:

```
const query = "cat_id=18%2C20%2C24&color_id=4";
```

or:

```
const urlObj = { cat_id: "18,20,24", color_id: "4" }
```

I need to create this:

```
const filteredItems = [
    {
      value:"18",
      queryKey:"cat_id"
    },
    {
      value:"20",
      queryKey:"cat_id"
    },
    {
      value:"24",
      queryKey:"cat_id"
    },
    {
      value:"4",
      queryKey:"color_id"
    }
]
```

Comment: is this in javascript?

Comment: Yes this is in javascript and I very close to to solution but still not find. In my solution I coverted the query url to object above I shown and use join and split map but still no final solution

Comment: great. Always add the [javascript] tag to questions in javascript, so people who know javascript well will see your problems.

Comment: "*[In] my solution I coverted the query url to object above I shown and use join and split map*" - can you share that attempted solution in your question, that way we may be able to help you realise why your attempt didn't succeed, that way you learn a solution to your problem *and* you gain insight into how JavaScript, or some of its methods, work.

Comment: @Thomas this is the solution Object.values(urlObj).join(",").split(",").map((v, idx) => {      
      return {
          queryKey:"1",
          value:v
      }
  })

but how to add queryKey when returning

Comment: @DavidThomas Please provide me the solution

Answer (score 0):

You cloud try `const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(query);`. More about this in the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: what I have done so far  
 `const url = Object.fromEntries(new URLSearchParams("cat_id=18%2C20%2C24&color_id=4"));
  const urlObj = { cat_id: "18,20,24", color_id: "4" }
  Object.values(urlObj).join(",").split(",").map((v, idx) => {      
      return {
          queryKey:"1",
          value:v
      }
  })`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here's one implementation:

```js
const urlObj = { cat_id: "18,20,24", color_id: "4" }

const filteredItems = Object.entries(urlObj).flatMap(([queryKey, value]) => {
  return value.split(",").map(v => ({ value: v, queryKey }))
})

console.log(filteredItems);
```